# Set up a database server that takes http requests

Tags: android, sql, database-server

Sorry for the basic question, but I can't find a way to word it properly to find what I need.

I'm making an Android application and I would like to make an SQL server database that I would put online (no localhost) to allow http requests to it, from my app. I want it online for academic purposes (no SQLite) but also to allow for multiple platforms.

Preferably, I would use a C# approach for the server so that I can use EntityFramework, but I don't know if it's a good way and I don't know how to put it online.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Make an API,which returns data from the server and your app communicates with the api and gets all the data. PHP is a fine enough server side language to communicate with your SQL db

Comment: There are about a billion questions on SO about this subject, did you look for anything before asking?